# JSONP get user data from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users using javascript in a html document

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, angularjs, api

I have a question regarding JSONP api in relation to the dummy data available on the URL http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users. Basicallly I wish to fetch the data using javascript in a html document and display the results in a unordered list tag.

I have this setup:

```
<

!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html data-ng-app="">
    <head>
        <title>Using AngularJS Directives and Data Binding</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $.ajax('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += "<ul><li>" + data + "</li></ul>";
            });
        </script>

        <div id="container"></div>
        <!--
        <div class="container">
            Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" /> {{ name }}
        </div> -->

    </body>
</html>
```

By inspecting my website locally we get the following result:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

in a single bulletin point.

I'm using jQuery and angularJS. I can tell I'm fetching some data, but I cannot figure out how to manipulate the data into it's subsection as can be seen at the url: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/.

Can someone shine some light on what I'm missing here? Attempting the data.id or data.name etc. will return undefined.

Bear in mind that I'm a beginner and have only just started working with APIs and JSONP. I'm sure the answer is relatively simple, but give it to me straight and pedagogically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You said you are using AngularJS but doing nothing with angularJS in your code snippet. Here is the AngularJS implementation for accessing [http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/][1] users data.

Give a close look how street,suite and city are being accessed.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>JSON API</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
     table, th , td {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
     }

     table tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
     }

     table tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #ffffff;
     }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <h2>My App</h2>
  <div ng-app = "" ng-controller = "userController">

     <table>
        <tr>
           <th rowspan="2">ID</th>
           <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
           <th rowspan="2">User Name</th>
           <th rowspan="2">Email</th>
           <th colspan="3">Address



           </th>              
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Street</th>
           <th>Suite</th>
           <th>City</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat = "user in users">
           <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
           <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
           <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
           <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
           <td>{{ user.address.street }}</td>
           <td>{{ user.address.suite }}</td>
           <td>{{ user.address.city }}</td>

        </tr>
     </table>
  </div>

  <script>
     function userController($scope,$http) {
        var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

        $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
           $scope.users = response;
        });
     }
  </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
    console.log(data[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your HTML. A *for loop* will populate an unordered list with the data, for each user.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html data-ng-app="">
    <head>
        <title>Using AngularJS Directives and Data Binding</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $.ajax('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                let response = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    response +=
                    `<ul>
                        <li>${data[i].name}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].email}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].address.city}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].address.street}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].address.suite}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].address.zipcode}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].address.geo.lat}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].address.geo.lng}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].phone}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].website}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].company.name}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].company.catchPhrase}</li>
                        <li>${data[i].company.bs}</li>
                    </ul>`
                }
                document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = response;
            });
        </script>

        <div id="container"></div>
        <!--
        <div class="container">
            Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" /> {{ name }}
        </div> -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Today you don't need to use jQuery to fetch data using a GET method. Just use the Fetch API. Below is an example of how to fetch data using browsers' native capabilities.

```
function fetchUsers() {

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then((res) => { return res.json() })
    .then((data) => {
        let response = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            response +=
        `<ul>
            <li>${data[i].name}</li>
            <li>${data[i].email}</li>
            <li>${data[i].address.city}</li>
            <li>${data[i].address.street}</li>
            <li>${data[i].address.suite}</li>
            <li>${data[i].address.zipcode}</li>
            <li>${data[i].address.geo.lat}</li>
            <li>${data[i].address.geo.lng}</li>
            <li>${data[i].phone}</li>
            <li>${data[i].website}</li>
            <li>${data[i].company.name}</li>
            <li>${data[i].company.catchPhrase}</li>
            <li>${data[i].company.bs}</li>
        </ul>`;
            }

            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = response;
        })
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // This event listener will trigger the function when the DOM is ready
    fetchUsers();
})
```

Functional example: https://codepen.io/th91vi/pen/KKVwZwm

You may want to read some documentation about the Fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score -1):

use `JSON.stringify(data)` it will convert the Javascript object into JSON string